# Authenticated scan strategy for large enterprise network

Tags: password-management, vulnerability-scanners

I have been tasked with using Qualys Vulnerability Scanner in order to perform scans within a large enterprise network.
Within this network there are Windows machines and Linux machines.
CyberArk has been installed but not yet implemented.

The idea is to scan the network even using the relative credentials, but the problems are:

1) CyberArk needs to be populated with the relative entries (user+password)

2) Linux/Unix hosts need to be scanned as well, but inserting the username+password on each asset, in a large enterprise network, is painstakingly hard.

An idea is to create **local** user accounts on each build of new machines, in order to be able to perform these scans -at least- for the new PCs, but what about the old ones? What could be an effective strategy in order to perform authenticated scans effectively, with a regard to security best practices?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the Linux machines tied into the Windows authentication database or part of their own authentication domain?

Comment: Hello PwdRsch, thanks for your reply. I don't know the environment that extensively, i'd need to ask confirmation on that, but i must assume there are machines which use both methods of authentication.

Comment: Sounds like you should be discussing this with the server administrators and being somewhat held up by the CyberArk deployment.

Comment: It's hard to believe a "large enterprise network" couldn't add users across the enterprise relatively easily.  If you can patch all your machines, you can add users to all your machines.  Also, look into SSH key authentication to avoid dealing with CyberArk for the Linux boxes.

Comment: Hello gowenfawr, thanks for your input. Indeed it should be relatively easy to do, however the environment contains multiple domains, not necessarily trusted between each other and not centralized, so it'll be more of a challenge. What I'm practically asking is a strategy to implement authenticated scans within the network without having to reach every single owner of each machine. I have taken note of your input regarding Linux hosts: I looked that Qualys supports such method of authentication, so it's something that I'm going to propose, definitely.